# Group Policy for Windows Mobile Devices

Tags: windows, mobile-devices

I have been searching for a solution to deploy group policy to Windows Mobile Devices. So far I have came up with nothing other that "Microsoft System Center Mobile Device Manager".

Has anyone else came across this issue? If so what did you use, If there is nothing else then I will use the previously mentioned solution but I hate to deploy a new server just for this reason.

*Note: These are not used for phone capabilities they will only be used as a pocket pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason you can't do it directly is because Windows Mobile devices cannot be joined to a domain as member objects, at least not directly. Prior to SCMDM being released I built an environment to support about 6k Windows Mobile devices where we created proxy accounts in the Active Directory and used them to handle secured access to our network resources and apply policies but we had to build our own client provisioning and management stack to do this and we had to build out a fairly complex infrastructure within the AD to support it. There are a number of third party solutions e.g. Credant that will do similar things but you will need to dedicate some servers for those if you opt for them.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done natively (last time I checked) in Active Directory.  There is a product called [GPAnywhere](http://www.fullarmor.com/products-gpanywhere.htm) that can do this.

[GPAnywhere http://www.fullarmor.com/documents/images/gpanywheremangageoutside.gif](http://www.fullarmor.com/documents/images/gpanywheremangageoutside.gif)